Python Selenium Web Driver Chrome Processcumulative issues in While Statement
I'm currently implementing the crawl function, but the crawl works fine, but the instance of selenium webdriver doesn't shut down normally, so it keeps accumulating and I found StackOverFlow to ask for a solution....
Chrome turns on through webdriver, moves pages through .get(), and executes crawling functions. In this process, driver.quit() is called through try except finally, but the instance does not end properly, so when i call the Task Manager, Chrome Porcess is not turned off.
The current situation is
The screen appears to be shutting down normally, but the Chrome is on when checking the details tab of the Task Manager.
And the funny thing is that this doesn't happen all the time, but there's roughly 50% chance of an instance remaining.
Sometimes instances are left in the early exit if statement, sometimes instances are left when they work normally, sometimes instances are shut down in the early exit if statement, and sometimes all instances are shut down normally, I can't guess where the real problem is...
Currently, I'm forcing the process to turn off every chrome instances  with taskkill as first aid, but I'm asking because I know it's not a fundamental solution.
It may be weird to use a translator because my English is not good enough, but please give me a good answer
This is my code.
app = Flask(__name__)


cafe_url = "URL"
cafe_menu_front = "URL"
cafe_menu_back = "URL"

crawl_results = {}
last_post_number = None

username = os.getenv('ID')
password = os.getenv('PW')

chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

def get_driver():
    chrome_options = Options()
    #chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    return driver

def analyze_image(image_url):
    yes_url = "URL"
    no_url = "URL"

    if image_url == yes_url:
        return 'YES'
    elif image_url == no_url:
        return 'NO'
    elif image_url == "UNKNOWN":
        return 'UNKNOWN'
    else:
        return 'MAYBE'


def get_latest_post_number(driver, menuid):
    driver.get(cafe_menu_front + menuid + cafe_menu_back)
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.switch_to.frame("cafe_main")
    posts = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div[1]/div")
    post_number = posts.text.strip()
    return post_number


def crawl_Alram(menuid):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    try:
        #post_number = get_latest_post_number(driver, menuid)

        driver.get(cafe_menu_front + menuid + cafe_menu_back)
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.switch_to.frame("cafe_main")
        post_number = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div[1]/div").text.strip()

        print(f"post_number : {post_number}")
        global last_post_number

        if last_post_number != post_number:
            last_post_number = post_number
        else:
            print(f"Already Notice")
            print(f"lastnumber : {last_post_number}")
            driver.quit()
            return

        driver.get(
            f"URL")
        print("post get success")
        time.sleep(3)

        driver.switch_to.frame("cafe_main")
        try:
            images = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.se-module.se-module-sticker a img.se-sticker-image")
            image_url = images.get_attribute('src')
            driver.quit()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            image_url = "UNKNOWN"
            driver.quit()

        result = analyze_image(image_url)
        results = {'url': image_url, 'result': result}

        global crawl_results
        crawl_results = results

        print(crawl_results)
        driver.quit()
    except Exception as e:
        driver.quit()
        print(f"Error in crawl_Alram: {e}")
    finally:
        driver.quit()


def crawl_periodically():
    while True:
        try:
            crawl_interval = random.randint(1, 5)
            crawl_Alram('9')
            os.system("taskkill /f /im chrome.exe /t")
            time.sleep(crawl_interval)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in crawl_periodically: {e}")


@app.route('/start_crawling', methods=['POST'])
def start_crawling():
    global cafe_url
    data = request.json
    cafe_url = data.get('cafe_url')

    if not cafe_url:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Missing parameters'}), 400

    threading.Thread(target=crawl_periodically, daemon=True).start()
    return jsonify({'message': 'Crawling started'})


@app.route('/results', methods=['GET'])
def results():
    return jsonify(crawl_results)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    threading.Thread(target=crawl_periodically, daemon=True).start()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)

I tried to change the position by putting driver.quit() here and there

why do you use quit() in every except and also in finally. You should use it only in one place because current code may try to close browser many times and it may raise another error
